# pnpjs sp with vue and vuetify datatable

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

If my name columns in sharepoint are empty, no data comes in with my get requests.

Using Vue with Vuetify tables.

get

```
this.$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("3dmodelassigndev").items // Development
.select("Assigned_x0020_To/Title", "Assigned_x0020_To/EMail","Company_x0020_Assigned_x0020_to", "Created", "Model_x0020_AssignedId", "ID")
.expand("Assigned_x0020_To")
.get().then((result) =>{
  vm.dataTableTwo = result;
  // console.log(vm.dataTableTwo);
});
```

Datatable

```
 <v-data-table
                :headers="headersTwo"
                :items="filteredItems"
                item-key="ID"
                :search="searchTwo"
                class="elevation-10"
              >
                <template v-slot:items="props">
                  <td>
                    {{ props.item.Assigned_x0020_To.Title }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{ props.item.Company_x0020_Assigned_x0020_to }}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {{ props.item.Created | formatDate }}
                  </td>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:no-results>
                  <v-alert
                    :value="true"
                    color="error"
                    icon="warning"
                  >
                    Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
                  </v-alert>
                </template>
              </v-data-table>
```

computed filter

```
filteredItems() {
  return this.dataTableTwo.filter((i) => {
    return !this.selected || (i.Model_x0020_AssignedId === this.selected);
  })
},
```

Is there a way to add them using the sp get?

It's a nested datatable expanding from other information and the tables that just have Assigned_x0020_To.Title render but get the cannot read undefined for other and no Assigned_x0020_To.Title is in the element.

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference.

```
this.$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("3dmodelassigndev").items // Development
.select("Assigned_x0020_To/Title", "Assigned_x0020_To/EMail","Company_x0020_Assigned_x0020_to", "Created", "Model_x0020_AssignedId", "ID")
.expand("Assigned_x0020_To")
.filter("Model_x0020_AssignedId eq '"+this.selected+"'")
.get().then((result) =>{
  vm.dataTableTwo = result;
  // console.log(vm.dataTableTwo);
});
```

Comment: i'm not trying to filter on call, it's more of the Assigned_x0020_To is empty on the sharepoint list, it won't pull that field at all and gives me errors on my table.

Comment: If the Assigned_x0020_To is empty on the SharePoint list, we can set the empty string in the results.